# Where Debug/Exceptions menu item gone in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Recently I noticed this menu item is gone in my new VS 2015. Is a feature, or just me?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's still there, just moved to be its own dockable window instead of a dialog:

```
Debug => Windows => Exception Settings
```

Comment: This menu has also disappeared?

Comment: @Mangist: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I suggest you ask a new question if it's not the exact same one as this.

Comment: I mean under Debug -> Windows there is no menu called Exception Settings. Not in my Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @Mangist: Which version of VS are you using? It's still there in my installation of VS 2015 Community edition... What windows *are* listed there?

Comment: This is VS 2015 Professional. Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints, Output, Diagnostics and Immediate. I was able to add the Exception Settings by going into Tools -> Customize and adding a button to the toolbar for Debug -> Exception Settings. I know this is strange, because it used to be there under VS 2013 under Debug -> Exceptions...